# HandBrake; Multiple Inputs

Tags: video-encoding

How can I encode and concatenate multiple videos using HandBrake / HandBrakeCLI??

In HandBrakeCLI when I run:
HandBrakeCLI -i file1.MPG -i file2.MPG -o out.m4v -O -e x264 -r 23.976 --pfr

the output only contains the second file!

Comment: This should be on [superuser](http://superuser.com/), not stack overflow.  See [this question](http://superuser.com/q/173300/31240) for more info on concatenating video files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot concatenate videos using HandBrakeCLI.

You can concatenate videos simply if they are in MPG-1

Using FFMPEG you can do

```
ffmpeg -i input1.avi -same_quant intermediate1.mpg
ffmpeg -i input2.avi -same_quant intermediate2.mpg
cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg
```

See the [FFmpeg FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f) for details.

Once the videos are concatenated, you can encode them however you like.

Comment: it's desynchroniez with audio.. my first video has no audio for instance. Also use -qscale 0 instead of -same_quant